# Binding a div CSS property to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to set div CSS property through Javascript object property.

```
var Tile = function(face) { 
    this.face = face;
    this.init = function(){
        var x = document.createElement("DIV");
        document.body.appendChild(x);
    }
};
```

Then I create an array of tiles:

```
tiles = [];

for (var i=0;i<4;i++){
    for (var j=0;j<4;j++){
        tiles.push(new Tile(arr[i*4+j]));
    }  
}

for (var i=0;i<4;i++){
    for (var j=0;j<4;j++){
        tiles[i*4+j].init();
    }
    document.write("<br>");
}
```

The problem is I can't change background-color of the div. When I'm trying to do this

```
tiles[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

I get the error: "Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined". I understand that I should access the property of the html div instead of Javascript object property. But I have no idea how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a reference to the style of the element as a property of your instance:

```js
function Tile (face) { this.face = face; };
Tile.prototype.init = function(){
  var x = document.createElement("div");
  this.style = x.style;
  document.body.appendChild(x);
};
```

```js
function Tile (face) { this.face = face; };
Tile.prototype.init = function(){
  var x = document.createElement("div");
  x.textContent = this.face;
  this.style = x.style;
  document.body.appendChild(x);
};
var tiles = [];
for (var i=0; i<16; ++i) {
  var tile = new Tile(i);
  tile.init();
  tiles.push(tile);
}
tiles[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make the node accessible. Right now your node doesn't exist on your "Tile" object. You could try something like this:

```
var Tile = function(face) { 
    this.node = document.createElement('div');
    this.face = face;
    this.init = function(){
        document.body.appendChild(this.node);
    }
};
```

then:

```
tiles[1].node.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

You can also make it private and use a setter:

```
var Tile = function(face) { 
    var node = document.createElement('div');

    this.face = face;
    this.init = function(){
        document.body.appendChild(node);
    };
    this.styleNode = function(prop, val){
        node.style[prop] = val;
    };
};

tiles[0].styleNode('backgroundColor', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are trying to modify .style on your Tile object, not the HTML object. You only have .init and .face defined, so you are calling .backgroundColor on undefined/null.

You need to expose `document.createElement("DIV")`. Something like this should work:

```
function Tile(face) {
    this.element = document.createElement("DIV");
    this.face = face;

    document.body.appendChild(element);
}

tiles.push(new Tile(face))

tiles[0].element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

The above code also automates the initialization process. If this is not desired, simply make a this.init function.

You could also make a method or something to simplify this process.